# Create team leader login session on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I tried to create the login session for team leader to check up how many staff in own group. I created a session variable like $_SESSION['teamcode']; it is able to access to the other pager. However it is unable to show up how mnay team member is on the screen.

Here is my login code :

```
    session_unset();
    session_start();

    $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT staffid, password, teamcode, accessid FROM tbl_staff WHERE staffid='%s' AND password='%s'",
    get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? $loginUsername : addslashes($loginUsername), get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? $password : addslashes($password)); 

    $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
    $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];    
   }
        switch ($loginStrGroup) {
     case $MM_fldUserAuthorization='2':
     header("Location: admin.php");
     break;
     case $MM_fldUserAuthorization='3':
    $row_LoginRS = mysql_fetch_array($LoginRS);
  $_POST['teamcode'] = $row_LoginRS['teamcode'];
    header("Location: team_member.php");
    break;
```

Access to team_member.php code is :

```
   session_start();
   ob_start();

    mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
    $query_RsStaff = "SELECT * FROM tbl_staff WHERE teamcode = '".$_GET['teamcode']."'";
    $query_limit_RsStaff = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_RsStaff, $startRow_RsStaff, $maxRows_RsStaff);
    $RsStaff = mysql_query($query_limit_RsStaff, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $totalRows_RsStaff = mysql_num_rows($RsStaff);
    $count=0;

    <body>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#dfdfdf"><?php echo $row_RsStaff['staffid']; ?></td>
    </body>
```

Thank you for any help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `session_start()` anywhere in your code. This needs to be called at the top of all pages, before any output is sent. Otherwise your `$_SESSION` variables won't retain their values.
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: I did not post on. I set up all of php pages which have session_start() and tried to change from $SESSION[]; to $_GET[] on team_member.php. It does not show up the all staff on same teamcode.

Comment: Ok, so it's not the session start. But your login code doesn't pass a `$_GET`. And there's no escaping your data either

Comment: I have tried to use $_GET[], $_POST[] or $SESSION[] on both of pages. It does not work.

Comment: But you're not passing the data. There's no code where you set any of those variables. Try changing `$_POST['teamcode'] = $row_LoginRS['teamcode'];` to `$_SESSION['teamcode'] = $row_LoginRS['teamcode'];` and then use that in the query on team_member

Comment: You're not escaping data either. Have you tried `echo mysql_error();`?

Comment: I tried to use firebug on FireFox to browse login.php. it shows up 302 Found. and the team_member.php shows up nothing of Mysql database.